# Paypal payment options

Tags: paypal

Hello I am trying to allow set pricing for an item and have an empty text box for persons to donate an additional amount to help cover the fees of another individual.

Anyone know how to make these 2 boxes add up when clicking checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery and do it like this:

html:

```
Your item:
<div id="item" data-price="5">$5 t-shirt</div>
Donation:
<input type="text" name="donation">
<input type="submit" id="checkout" value="checkout">
```

javascript:

```
$(function() { // execute when dom is ready

$('#checkout').click(function(event) {
  var itemPrice = Number($('#item').data().price);
  var donationAmount = Number($('input[name=donation]').val());
  if (!donationAmount) {
    alert("Please enter a number in the donation field.");
  } else {
    alert("Your checkout total is " + total);
  }
});

});
```

Comment: I didn't see where I can enter the java on the personal account... here is what I currently have :(

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2N6VM4CDRB7KE">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Registration options">Registration options</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">

Comment: <option value="Pre-Registration">Pre-Registration $35.00 USD</option>
 <option value="Registration">Registration $40.00

Comment: USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Character Name">Character Name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Angel Donation</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">

Comment: <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>